# Json.net on deserialize change property type and name

Tags: c#, json.net

With json.net when I deserialize a json string, I need to map a json List to another field and convert type.

To make it clear, I have this class (it's generated code and I can't change it):

```cs
[Serializable]
public partial class Nbgv
{
    public virtual IReadOnlyList<string> BuildMetadataWithCommitId => BuildMetadataWithCommitIdInternal.AsReadOnly();
    internal List<string> BuildMetadataWithCommitIdInternal { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

I have this json string:

```cs
string json = @"{
    ""BuildMetadataWithCommitId"": [
        ""c390a213b7""
    ]
}";
```

As you can see `BuildMetadataWithCommitId` depends on `BuildMetadataWithCommitIdInternal`.

I tried several things with a custom resolver but nothing worked. I did not find how to tell json.net if you find a property that is a generic list, map it to the field ending with *Internal.

```cs
private class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.Writable = true;
        if (IsList(property.PropertyType))
        {
            property.PropertyName += "Internal";
            property.PropertyType = ToList(property.PropertyType);
        }

        return property;
    }

    private Type ToList(Type t)
    {
        var genericListType = typeof(List<>);
        var specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(t.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        return specificListType;
    }

    private bool IsList(Type t)
    {
        if (t == null) return false;

        var res = t.IsGenericType &&
                   t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IReadOnlyList<>));

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I tried several things with a custom resolver but nothing worked.* then can you please share what you tried?  Can you modify the type `Nbgv` and add Json.NET attributes, or data contract attributes?

Comment: I cannot change the Nbgv class it is generated by a tool. And I cannot change the json also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your `CustomContractResolver` only changes the [`PropertyName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_PropertyName.htm) and [`PropertyType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_PropertyType.htm) of the returned [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm), however the underlying [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.8) from which it was created is still that of the public surrogate property, not the private internal "real" property.  Thus the [`ValueProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ValueProvider.htm), among other things, will still be wrong.

What you need to do instead is to generate a `JsonProperty` for the internal property, correct its name and accessibility, and return it *in place of* the `JsonProperty` for the public property.  This will ensure that the serializer will serialize and deserialize the internal property instead of its public surrogate.

The following contract resolver does the job:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    const string InternalSuffix = "Internal";

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = member as PropertyInfo;
        var jProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property != null && jProperty != null && memberSerialization != MemberSerialization.Fields && !jProperty.HasMemberAttribute)
        {
            var replacementName = jProperty.UnderlyingName + InternalSuffix;

            // Check for replacement property.
            var replacementProperty = jProperty.DeclaringType.GetProperty(replacementName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (replacementProperty != null
                && replacementProperty.GetGetMethod(true) != null && replacementProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null
                && ReplacementTypeCompatible(property, replacementProperty.PropertyType)
                )
            {
                var replacementJProperty = base.CreateProperty(replacementProperty, memberSerialization);
                replacementJProperty.PropertyName = jProperty.PropertyName;
                if (!replacementJProperty.Readable && replacementProperty.GetGetMethod(true) != null)
                    replacementJProperty.Readable = true;
                if (!replacementJProperty.Writable && replacementProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null)
                    replacementJProperty.Writable = true;
                return replacementJProperty;
            }

            // Check for replacement field.
            var replacementField = jProperty.DeclaringType.GetField(replacementName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (replacementField != null
                && ReplacementTypeCompatible(property, replacementField.FieldType)
                )
            {
                var replacementJProperty = base.CreateProperty(replacementField, memberSerialization);
                replacementJProperty.PropertyName = jProperty.PropertyName;
                replacementJProperty.Readable = true;
                replacementJProperty.Writable = true;
                return replacementJProperty;
            }
        }

        return jProperty;
    }

    static bool ReplacementTypeCompatible(PropertyInfo property, Type replacementType)
    {
        // Add here whatever restrictions you need
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(IReadOnlyList<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            && replacementType.IsGenericType && typeof(List<>).IsAssignableFrom(replacementType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            && replacementType.GetGenericArguments().SequenceEqual(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use it, cache an instance of the resolver somewhere for [performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver):

```
static IContractResolver customContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
```

And deserialize like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = customContractResolver,
};
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Nbgv>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- In your question, you state *I need to map a json List to another **field***, however in the actual example the underlying member is a **property**.  Thus in [`CreateProperty()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm) I check for both types of replacement.  If in your production code you only need one or the other, you can remove the unneeded logic.
- The check `!jProperty.HasMemberAttribute` prevents properties explicitly marked with [`[JsonProperty]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) from being replaced.  This seems correct but you can remove the check if you don't want it.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H84Zza).